# debian maintainer scripts - finding the actual ".deb" file path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb

I've created a .deb package for my product, and added preinst, postinst, prerm, postrm maintainer scripts to be called during installation/removal.
I need to access the actual installation file from within those scripts.

For example, say the user ran the following command:
dpkg -i /home/me/my_package.deb

Then, I would like to know the path /home/me/my_package.deb.

I know that there's an environment variable named SUDO_COMMAND, but it doesn't contain the file name under all circumstances, so this solution is not good enough.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should create one script for that which install your `.deb` package. For example `sh script.sh /path/my.deb` and make your script to accept path and `.deb` file as a command line.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no control over the way my clients install the package. So I can't make them use any wrapper script.